# Estimating $I(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-2s} dz $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $$I(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-2s} dz . $$
For a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$. Is it true that $I(x) = 0$ for $x \in \Omega$ and $I(x) = \infty$ for $x \in \mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega$?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean $s>0$. We will denote by $c_N$ the $N-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Pick $x\in\Omega$. Then, there exists a ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$ of radius $\varepsilon>0$ centered at $x$. We have the estimate
$$ I(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus \Omega} \vert x -z \vert^{-N-2s} dz
\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus B_\varepsilon(x)} \vert x -z \vert^{-N-2s} dz
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^N \setminus B_\varepsilon(0)} \vert z \vert^{-N-2s} dz
= c_N \int_\varepsilon^\infty r^{N-1} r^{-N-2s} dr
= c_N \int_\varepsilon^\infty r^{-1-2s} dr
= \frac{c_N}{2s} \varepsilon^{-2s}, $$
where we switched to spherical coordinates to compute the integral. On the other hand, we do not have $I(x)=0$. To see this, we note that there exists $R>0$ such that $\Omega \subseteq B_R(0)$ as $\Omega$ is bounded. Thus, we have
$$ I(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus \Omega} \vert x -z \vert^{-N-2s} dz
\geq \int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus B_R(0)} \vert x -z \vert^{-N-2s} dz 
= \frac{c_N}{2s} R^{-2s}>0.$$

Now we will see that we have $I(x)=\infty$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \overline{\Omega}$. There exists $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \Omega$. Thus, we have
$$ I(x) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus \Omega} \vert x -z \vert^{-N-2s} dz
\geq \int_{B_\delta(x)} \vert x -z \vert^{-N-2s} dz
= \int_{B_\delta(0)} \vert z \vert^{-N-2s} dz
= c_N \int_0^\delta r^{-1-2s} dr = \infty. $$
The interesting question is now what happens for $x\in \overline{\Omega}$. This depends now really on the geometry of $\Omega$. For example consider $N=2$ first
$$ \Omega = \{  (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ r\in [0,1), \ \theta \in (\pi/2, 2\pi) \}. $$
Then, we have
$$ I(0,0) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B_1(0)} \vert z \vert^{-2-2s} dz + \int_{\{  (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ r\in [0,1), \ \theta \in [0,\pi/2]  \}} \vert z \vert^{-2-2s} dz
= \frac{4\pi}{2s} + 3\pi \int_0^1 r^{-1-2s}dr =\infty.$$
On the other hand, let us consider
$$ \Omega = B_1(0) \setminus \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ : \ x\in [0,1], 0\leq y \leq x^{2+3s} \}.$$
Then we have
$$ I(0,0) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B_1(0)} \vert z \vert^{-2-2s} dz + \int_{\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ : \ x\in [0,1], 0\leq y \leq x^{2+3s} \} } \vert z \vert^{-2-2s} dz
= \frac{4\pi}{2s} + \int_0^1 \int_0^{x^{2+3s}} (x^2+y^2)^{(-2-2s)/2} dy dx
\leq \frac{4\pi}{2s} + \int_0^1 \int_0^{x^{2+3s}} x^{-2-2s} dy dx
= \frac{4\pi}{2s} + \int_0^1 x^{s} dx <\infty.$$

Of course we could also consider $\Omega = B_1(0)\setminus [0,1] \times \{0\}$, then the computation would be even easier (because $I$ does not "see" changes on a null set).

So in short, the decay at infinity is enough to make the integral converge. The real problem are the singularities, i.e. the blow-ups are too big.